# Have "$\delta$-measures" (or anything like them) been studied before?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, terminology

I don't like that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x$ fails to define a signed measure $\hat{f}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ via the formula $$\hat{f}(A) = \int_A f d\mu,$$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. So I came up with something called a "$\delta$-measure" to get around this.

> **Question.** Have "$\delta$-measures" (or anything like them) been studied before?

Here's what I'm thinking:

> **Definition 0.** A *$\delta$-measureable space* is a set equipped with one of its [$\delta$-rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-ring).
>
> **Definition 1.** Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ denote a $\delta$-measurable space. Then a *signed $\delta$-measure* on $X$ is a function $\mu:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following axioms:
>
> - $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
> - If $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ are disjoint, then $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) +\mu(B).$
> - If $A : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ is monotone-decreasing, then $\mu\left(\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}A_i\right) = \inf_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_i).$
> - If $A : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ consists of pairwise disjoint terms, and if $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_i)$ converges absolutely, and $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}A_i\right) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_i).$
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $X$ denote a topological space. Then a set $A \subseteq X$ is said to be *$\delta$-compact* iff $A$ is in the $\delta$-ring generated by the compact subsets of $X$.
>
> **Definition 3.** Each topological space is to be viewed as a $\delta$-measurable space by taking the distinguished $\delta$-ring as consisting of the $\delta$-compact subsets.
>
> **Idea.** Given a topological space $X$ equipped with a sufficiently-nice measure Borel measure $\mu$, and given a locally-integrable function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we should get a corresponding signed $\delta$-measure $\hat{f}$ given by $$\hat{f}(A) = \int_A f d\mu,$$ where $A$ is assumed to range over the $\delta$-compact subsets of $X$.

Comment: A natural additional question is whether, for $X$ sigma-locally compact, there exists a theory of integration with respect to $\delta$-measures for functions $g \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ that sufficiently quickly vanish at infinity.